# Trigger for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that will send me an email once a figure in a cell reaches a certain number. I tried setting up triggers, but it doesn't work for what I need.

I need some code to open up the spreadsheet every 2 hours and then check the cell. If the number is greater than what I want, then it emails me.

Does anyone have their own code that I can add to my email function that will do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**The following code will check the value inside a cell and if the number inside the cell is greater than your specified limit, it will send an alert to the given email address.**

```
function sendEmail() {
  // get the number in the specified cell. Here I used the cell B2 for reference
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowNum = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue(); //take the value to rowNum

  if(rowNum > your_number_limit ){
    var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
    var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail("youremailaddress", subject, message); 
  }
// Send Alert Email.

}
```

To check the value every 2 hours do the following

From the Script Editor,

- choose **Resources > Current project's triggers**. You see a panel with the message No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
- Click the link that says **No triggers set up**. Click here to **add one now**.
- Under **Run**, select the function you want executed on schedule.
- Under **Events**, select Time-driven.
- On the first drop-down list that appears, select **Hour timer**
- set interval of hours for 2 hours.
- Click Save.

*To ensure that the script runs at the correct time for a particular time zone, click **File > Properties**, **select a time zone and click Save**.*

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there any way to have the script check to different cells and email me if one or both exceeds my per-defined value?

Comment: `var rowNum1 = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();  var rowNum2 = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();                                                                              if(rowNum1 > your_value || rowNum2 > your_value){ //write email sending code here};`  //this code will get data from both B2 and B3 cells. Inside the if condition it will check either one of them exceeds your predefined value.